# Parsing, Planning and Optimizing Prepared Statements

Tags: postgresql

[PostgreSQL (2nd Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672327562) by Douglas and Douglas notes:

> Use server-side procedures (triggers and functions) to perform common operations. A server-side procedure is parsed, planned and optimized the first you use it, not every time you use it.

When using a prepared statement, is it parsed, planned and optimized only on the first time it's used (similar to triggers and functions per the quoted text), or each time it's used?

Comment: Could you please replace your image with text? Right now it's not clear what the question is without the image.

Comment: Which book are you referring to?

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/PostgreSQL-2nd-Korry-Douglas/dp/0672327562 @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: @George.Palacios - I updated my question - thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PostgreSQL doc for [PREPARE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-prepare.html) is clear about the advantages of prepared statements in terms of performance:

> PREPARE creates a prepared statement. A prepared statement is a
>   server-side object that can be used to optimize performance. When the
>   PREPARE statement is executed, the specified statement is parsed,
>   analyzed, and rewritten. When an EXECUTE command is subsequently
>   issued, the prepared statement is planned and executed. This division
>   of labor avoids repetitive parse analysis work, while allowing the
>   execution plan to depend on the specific parameter values supplied.